# How to prevent underlay child window from receving messages (windows API)

Tags: windows, winapi, message-queue

[image]

now I have 2 child windows overlapping on each others.

- first one is a button. (Created First)
- second one is just a black Rectangle created after the button and the list box under it(in the Linked image)

when the black child Created it's been painted and get the button covered correctly . and also when I hover the mouse over the area of the black child window it receives messages, but when the mouse enters the -hidden- underlay Button area , the button is repainting and clipping it's area from the overlapped black rect child window ,meaning it receives messages.

**How can I prevent this button from receiving any messages when it's sibling -black child- is over?**

Thanks in advance

the creating code of the black child

```
CreateWindowEx(0,controlerclassname,"",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,5,5,300,300,Hmainwin,0,Hinstance,0);
```

the WM_PAINT processing

```
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            RECT rc;
            HBRUSH Hbrush;
            GetClientRect(hwnd,&rc);
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
            Hbrush =CreateSolidBrush(RGB(10,10,10)); //(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH); // 
            SelectObject(hdc,Hbrush);
            Rectangle(hdc,rc.left,rc.top,rc.right,rc.bottom);
            EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
```

The Button Creating line

```
CreateWindowExA(0,"BUTTON" ,"Creat New Top Level Window", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_FLAT, // Button Create
        mainwndrc.left+10, mainwndrc.top+10 ,200,30,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_BTN_NEW,Hinstance,0);
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. Use `WS_EX_CLIPSIBLINGS` to stop sibling windows painting over each other.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Do you mean WS_CLIPSIBLINGS ? if so, yes I tried this style with the black child , and the result was the areas over the button is clipped from the black window - never painted when the black child is being paint- , and when I try it with the button , it has nothing to do with the button because I need the black child to completely hide the button and receive all the messages when the mouse over it.

Comment: Yes WS_ not WS_EX sorry. Set WS_CLIPSIBLINGS on the button to stop it drawing over the black child, and make sure the black child is on top of the button using `SetWindowPos` to fix the z-order.

Comment: @JonathanPotter  yeeeeeeeeeeees , It worked, thaaaaaank you , you are a win 32 hero :* :*